# Calling processMessage() from bot.on('send')

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, botframework

I am writing tests for my bot using Jest, and I have the following code:

```
let bot;
let conn;
let index = 0;
let responses = [];
let expectedResponses = [];

beforeEach(() => {
    let connector = new builder.ConsoleConnector();
    bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
    conn = connector;
});

test('test case 1 jeff', () => {
    bot.library(require('../dialogs/inputRecognizer').createLibrary());
    // the main dialog "/" should start "inputRecognizer:/"
    // as it can be seen [https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/858aad96cdd1fabbf7f9a29ee797eb03111d7cba/Node/core/tests/Dialogs.js][1] the code below seems to be identical to the one shown in examples
    bot.dialog('/', [
        (session) => {
            session.beginDialog('inputRecognizer:/');
        }
    ]);

    basicMessages.forEach(o => {if (o.in) {expectedResponses.push(o.in)}});

    bot.on('send', function (message) {
        responses.push(message.text);
        index++;
        if (index < testMessages.length) {
            conn.processMessage(basicMessages[index].out);
        } else {
            expect(responses).toEqual(expectedResponses);
        }
    });

    conn.processMessage(basicMessages[0].out);
});
```

The code runs fine and inputs all my messages into the connector. However, the second message is treated as a new dialog, as are all the following messages. So what I get is the dialog starting over and over again.

I've looked into the BotFramework tests at GitHub and it looks like they're using a similar approach (trigger the first processMessage outside the 'send' event handler, and call the next ones from the handler).

How do I get processMessage to not restart my dialog every time? I assume it's a problem with my dialog, maybe?

My dialog code ("inputRecognizer:/"):

```
lib.dialog('/', [
    function (session) {
        // it always executes this part
        builder.Prompts.text(session,
            `Please type your inquiry!`);
    },
    (session, result) => {
        if (result.response) {
            // and it never gets to here
```

Edit: `basicMessages` is this:

```
module.exports = [
    {
        out: 'hi',
        in: 'Please type your inquiry!',
    },
    {
        out: 'aaa',
        in: 'Please type your inquiry!'
    },
    {
        out: 'aaa',
        in: 'Please type your inquiry!'
    },
    {
        out: 'aaaa',
        in: 'Please type your inquiry!'
    },
    {
        out: 'aa',
        in: 'Please type your inquiry!'
    }
];
```

Comment: I am confused by the code that you posted. I see one `/` dialog under test and then you show another with the two step waterfall that you say fails reaching the second step. Can you maybe share your full test case?

Comment: The first dialog calls the 'inputRecognizer:/' dialog. And the second piece of code is the inputRecognizer dialog itself.

Comment: And what's in the `basicMessages`?

Comment: If you run your bot, does the message reach the waterfall step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your `basicMessages` are wrong: your `expectedResponses` array looks like:

```
["Please type your inquiry!", "Please type your inquiry!", "Please type your inquiry!", "Please type your inquiry!", "Please type your inquiry!"]
```

which I don't think it's expected as you are adding `messages.Text` to the list of `responses` you later use to assert.

Also, you don't need the `createLibrary();`

You can just use `bot.library(require('../dialogs/inputRecognizer'));`

I recreated your project ([GitHub](https://github.com/ejadib/NodeBotTests)) and the code reaches the waterfall after the prompt just fine.

Comment: The basicMessages are correct, they're just verifying that it's not working, instead of working. However, when I cloned your code, it works just fine. I removed createLibrary() from my code and it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: It still starts the waterfall from the top every time I send a message to the dialog.

Comment: Can you post the correct version of the basicMessages?. Are the tests working fine on my code version with the correct basicMessages?

Comment: In your code the tests work fine, in my code the waterfall restarts every time. basicMessages are the same in both.

Comment: Interesting, any difference in the code base? What version of the BotBuilder SDK are u using?

Comment: I used v3.7.0... maybe is that? It must be any difference :)

Comment: I updated the botbuilder package and now it doesn't restart the waterfall. I'm still getting a bunch of errors, but the waterfall issue is resolved, so I am marking the question as answered. Thank you very much!